# How to Configure VSFTPD?

Tags: configuration, ftp, vsftpd

I've been at this for hours. I basically want to be able to upload / manage a website on my new Ubuntu server, using FileZilla from my windows 7 machine.

I have installed vsftpd on the server, but I am stuck on the configuration part. I have read 10 different recipies online, but none seem to get me where I want to go.

I basically want a username/password combination that I can use to access the www folder in apache and upload files.

Can you help me create this user and write the correct vsftpd configuration so that it's safe and only I can upload php/html/css etc directly into the apache. Also create folders etc... Everything I am used to from a windows server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why go to through the hassle of setting up an insecure FTP server if you can also use SFTP which encrypts the traffic? Something like [How to setup a SFTP server with users chrooted in their homedirectories?](http://askubuntu.com/q/49271/6969)

Comment: is there a way to configure the SFTP server that comes with OpenSSH?

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm new to this. But what i'd do is mount the file under a users home file.
edit your fstab file to do this on boot.

Answer (score 0):

I was learning about this a while ago and found a youtube video. It will probably go through some things that you already know, but I think that it will answer you question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-W_mDGX1bY