# How can I prevent a user from navigating out of their home folder with SFTP?

Tags: permissions, sftp

I want to set up an account purely for someone/thing to access via SFTP.

I have already setup the home directory as `/media/HardDrive/FTP`

Is there any way to prevent this user (Bob) from accessing `/media/HardDrive`?

Probably a really simple thing to do but I want to lock them out of `/media/HardDrive`.

I'm still getting to grips with the whole Linux operating system so a step-by-step instruction guide on how to do this would be really helpful as I'm not totally sure what I need to do.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is `chroot`. I'm sure such a Q&A already exists here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a *root jail* (commonly called a *chroot*) for the user logging in to your server. The SSH daemon (which handles incoming `sftp` traffic) has a `ChrootDirectory` property which can do this.

Though it is no detailed step by step guide, [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) on AskUbuntu may get you on your way. A step by step walkthrough is provided in [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/).