# installing ubuntu base system in home folder as non-root

Tags: ssh, chroot

I don't have root acess to a server which is running centos. I need a minimal ubuntu chroot environment in my $HOME . (just the apt-get, repositories etc to install packages and run them in terminal. display is not needed)

I was looking around the internet to find any information on this but most of the [tutorials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) require root access.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sudo` command and then it will ask your password so if you give your password it will get `root` privilege. and ask your system admin to incorporate your user into `sudoers` file

The command would be like  this

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I can't get sudo or su access. That was the point of the question.

Comment: ask your system admin to add your user in the `sudoers` file with some limited permeation  like `your_user_id    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`