# Grant SSH access to subfolder which is owned by root

Tags: ssh

I have a folder /srv/jarvis which has punch of subfolder and on of them is called carl (/srv/jarvis/carl)

jarvis Dir has these rights

```
drwxrwxrwx 12 root root    4096 Jun  9 11:34 jarvis
```

And Carl has these rights

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 carl carl 4096 Jun  9 13:02 carl
```

In the /etc/ssh/sshd_config i have added these lines

```
Match user carl
    ChrootDirectory /srv/jarvis/carl
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

But if i add those lines and do service ssh restart

then the user cant login into that server Write fails: Broken pipe. And if remove tose lines from sshd_config he can login again but i dont want that

I want that the use can access only to /srv/jarvis/carl/ and do there what ever he wants
Also he cant do any of the root stuff :)

How can i fix thoes problems

Comment: I have a similar setup with the same general config - in mine, I have double-quotes around the username (i.e. `Match User "carl"`), but the documentation I can find seems to indicate this may be unnecessary.  Do you have a `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` line somewhere in your `sshd_config`?

Comment: yes, i have Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Comment: In my config, I have the line you mentioned commented out, and am specifically using `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` instead of the external sftp-server.  Regarding the `internal-sftp` statement, the documentation states `Alternately the name 'internal-sftp' implements an in-process 'sftp' server. This may simplify configurations using ChrootDirectory to force a different filesystem root on clients.`.  I'd try commenting out your `Subsystem` statement and trying it with `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` instead.

Comment: i tried also to comment out that line and switch to Subsystem sftp internal-sftp but no help

Comment: I found some other [useful notes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) that indicate your `carl` folder should be owned by root (`chown root /srv/jarvis/carl`).  Your current permissions there look fine.  It won't allow write-access for `carl`, so you may need to put a subfolder there owned by him to write stuff to.  If you still have no luck, see if you can find anything helpful in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: An amendment to the chroot permissions note - from the Archwiki (YMMV), it seems like you could keep your `carl` permissions if you change your `ChrootDirectory` to `/srv/jarvis/%u`, and modify the permissions on `jarvis` with `chmod 755 /srv/jarvis`.

Comment: still no luck
auth log shows that

 21:10:18 localhost sshd[16609]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/srv/"
Jun 11 21:10:18 localhost sshd[16596]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user carl

Answer (score 0):

From your auth.log notes, it appears that this is a permissions issue.  Specifically the log line that says

```
21:10:18 localhost sshd[16609]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/srv/"
```

If you leave your `sshd_config` line reading `ChrootDirectory /srv/jarvis/carl`, as it is currently, then every directory in this path need to have the following characteristics:

- It needs to be owned by the root user (group is not important)
- It cannot be group or world writable (i.e. would need `chmod 755`)

Again, these apply to `/srv`, `/srv/jarvis`, and `/srv/jarvis/carl`.  Unfortunately, the result of this is that this user `carl` will not be able to write into his top-level directory (after the chroot takes effect).  One way around this is to prepare a subdirectory there and give him ownership of it, so he has some place to create files and folders.

---

I haven't tested it myself, but some discussions of this topic across the web has led me to believe that if you change your `ChrootDirectory` directive to read:

```
ChrootDirectory /srv/jarvis/%u
```

(which, in your case, will always mean `/srv/jarvis/carl` since he's the only one that would match), `sshd` may treat the wildcard-matching folder differently.  You may be able to get away with the user carl owning the `carl` folder this way.  Again, no guarantees.  If not, the first method described should work.