# How to lock down SFTP user?

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp, chown

I really need some help, I have been trying to jail a user using `ubuntu`.

Thing to note:

1. `james` is the user
2. `sshusers` is the group
3. `/home/james/upload/` is the directory where I wish to lock user

**sshd_config:**

```
AllowGroups sshusers 

Match Group sshusers
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u/upload/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I [followed an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/134442/114204) on askubuntu , here are my commands

```
sudo chown root /home/james
sudo chmod go-w /home/james
sudo mkdir /home/james/upload
sudo chown james:sshusers /home/james/upload
sudo chmod ug+rwX /home/james/upload
```

**Problem:**

I get this error

```
Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I investigated in the logs, and I found this:

> fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component
>   "/home/james/upload/"

But if I run the following commands

```
sudo chown root /home/james/upload
sudo chmod go-w /home/james/upload
```

It works perfect , user can connect, folder is locked **BUT cannot drop files** in the directory

```
Status: Listing directory /
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\Program\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-1\empty_file_yq744zm
Command:    put "C:\Users\Program\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-1\empty_file_yq744zm" "test"
Error:  /test: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
```

Please advice, I have search google so much all the links are purple now (visited `:P`)

I'm using filezilla client to test `SFTP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ChrootDirectory` directive expects that the chroot directory be owned by `root`, and not writable by anybody else. So you *cannot* jail a user to a directory and allow the user permission to write to that directory. You can:

#### Chroot to home, upload to `upload/`

The first set of commands you tried are correct for this:

```
sudo chown root /home/james
sudo chmod go-w /home/james
sudo mkdir /home/james/upload
sudo chown james:sshusers /home/james/upload
sudo chmod ug+rwX /home/james/upload
```

However, the option in `sshd_config` would be:

```
Match Group sshusers
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

(`%h` is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, equivalent to `/home/%u` for most cases.)
In addition, to limit the visibility of folders in `/home/james`, and restrict write permission there, use the recursive options for `chown` and `chmod` in the first command for `/home/james`, and remove `read` permissions. The modified set would look like:

```
sudo chown root /home/james -R 
sudo chmod go-rwx /home/james -R  # Disallow traversing any directory in home 
sudo chmod go+x /home/james       # Allow traversing this directory
sudo mkdir /home/james/upload
sudo chown james:sshusers /home/james/upload
sudo chmod ug+rwx /home/james/upload
```

Now the user should only be able to access `/home/james/upload`, or `/upload`.

#### Chroot to upload, upload to `upload/some_directory`

Pretty much the same as above, replacing `/home/james/` with `/home/james/upload`, and `/home/james/upload` with `/home/james/upload/some_directory`. No particular gains.

#### Change the home directory of `james` to `/upload`

The usual behaviour of ChrootDirectory is: "After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory."
So we change `james`'s home directory:

```
usermod -d /upload  user
```

Then set the `ChrootDirectory` to `/home/%u`. Use the same restrictions in the first option.

Comment: this make sense, but how would the users manage to change directory to upload ? I have seen linux servers that would restrict you to a folder just by logging in?

Comment: @meda The usual behaviour of `ChrootDirectory` is: "After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory." So say you have `/some/dir/chroot/home/james`, and you set `ChrootDirectory` to `/some/dir/chroot`, it will change the directory to the home folder, relative to that: `/some/dir/chroot/home/james`. That's probably how those servers do it.

Comment: @meda see update.

Comment: This clarifies a lot @muru, I cant try it now , but I get back to u thanks a lot

Comment: unfortunately I get the same result

Comment: all I need to do is restrict a user to an folder where he can upload folder, I dont know why this is so hard. can you re adapt your answer to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok Now I manage to connect to the right folder, by passing upload name to the command, but how can I do it directly

Comment: @meda I am not around a PC now. I'll test it out with FileZilla and update when I am.

Comment: ok no problem, I went to the office just to try your suggestion, so take your time and let me know when u get a chance

Answer (score 0):

The built-in sftp chroot mechanism in OpenSSH requires that the chroot directory be owned by root (and not writable by users).  This could be a pain if the directory is an SMB/CIFS share for example, where you'd have to do bind mount.

One of the more flexible solution would be to use MySecureShell (http://mysecureshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
apt install mysecureshell
```

It works without any modification to your default OpenSSH settings.  All you need to do is make your SFTP user login shell to mysecureshell, and it will take care of the ACL/virtual chroot for you.  See the documentation for details,

For example, once you have installed MySecureShell, you can then add an SFTP user (restricted to their home directory) as below,

```
sudo useradd -m -d /home/sftpuser01 --shell /usr/bin/mysecureshell sftpuser01
```

From the above, the user 'sftpuser01' will get virtual chrooted to '/home/sftpuser01' in SFTP session.

It also provide a lot of flexible options to control ACL, group etc by configuring '/etc/ssh/sftp-config'.
Please refer to http://mysecureshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html for details.