# How to set up an SFTP user with no ability to traverse the directory tree

Tags: chroot, sftp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. My goal is to have an SFTP user(s) log into the sever remotely with permission to upload or download anything from the directory they land in, but NOT be able to traverse folders.

All SFTP user home directories should be /storage/digital/uploads
So if I have user bob, his home directory would be /storage/digital/uploads/bob

SELinux and server firewall are disabled. I will be using NAT on my router to pass SFTP traffic.

I will be adding more users to this setup so it can't be all about bob. Suzy will need her own SFTP directory in /storage/digital/uploads as well.

Please, any help would be great, I'm running out of time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes)

Comment: I read that possible duplicate but it is troubleshooting a broken pipe. I don't have a broken pipe. Also, following those directions, users are still able to traverse directories, but not able to write in any of them.
I'd prefer my user(s) be able to see only their folder with no navigation opportunities.

Comment: Can't you set permissions to keep them out of the other users' homes from that point?

Comment: No I am not but it may be due to my own lack of know-how here. I've set this up and blown it out so many times now I'm just lost. None of these write ups are getting me anywhere