# Can you use SFTP with VSFTPD

Tags: vsftpd, sftp

I have installed vsftpd on my Ubuntu 16.04 server, and can connect fine using SFTP for a single user.

I want to set up additional users and give them the ability to connect to their home directories (or a sub directory of that), via SFTP too. I also want to (chroot) jail them so they cannot navigate outside of this directory they are redirected to on login.

I've spent a lot of time reading about, and configuring the /etc/vsftpd.conf file, but cannot get this to work with SFTP in the way I have described, and believe that therefore it is only for FTP - am I correct in this statement, and if so, does anyone know of a solution? I really would prefer to use SFTP rather than the hassle of FTPS.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

SFTP establishes a connection over SSH protocol. If you have `openssh-server` installed you can connect with any system user and password as long as this function was not disabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. It is not related to vsftp.

Add new users:

```
sudo adduser username
```

Then connect to the system:

```
ssh username@host
sftp localhost
```

You will be prompted for a password for all commands above.

**Update**: How to jail users to their home with sftp can be [found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes).

Comment: This doesn't jail the user as the OP is requesting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back that's useful - yes, I also need to jail users to their home directory (thank you Thomas)