# Point an SFTP user to its working directory without listing other user's directory

Tags: server, permissions, sftp, chroot, restricted-access

I am working on configuring an SFTP server on Ubuntu Server 18.04. I want to create SFTP accounts that point directly to their working directories without listing others. For example if the real working directory on the server is `/sftpdir1/sftpdir2/user1`, the user should see it as `/` and not `/user1` like when using chrootdirectory: when I login via FileZilla I should find as shown in the image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRlvD.png) where I can upload and download files.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes)

Comment: @pLumo no it doesn't. Actually I've tried this obviously but if there is many users assigned to the same group, By logging in , all their directories will be listed, the actual user will find him/her self under /username but I want him/her to ber under / where he/her can download and upload, but this is impossible with  the chrootdirectory because it is owned by the root !