# How to restrict a SSH Key user access?

Tags: server, ssh

So, I have a "personal" server, and it is only being used by me at the moment, but now I want some of my friends to be able to download files through `scp` using a SSH Key that they will provide to me, but I don't want them to be able to enter my server via SSH nor see the files that I have.
Is there a way that I can limit what they can and can't do via their SSH Key?
If not, is there other alternatives besides restricting a SSH Key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes)

Comment: Restrict them to SFTP only. In newer versions, scp uses the SFTP protocol, but even if it didn't sftp is still the better way

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called `scponly` that is used exactly to achieve what you want. You must set this program as a shell for a user that you want to restrict only to scp.

However, the program is not available in Ubuntu repositories, so you need to compile it from source. [Here](https://orcacore.com/enable-scponly-ubuntu-22-04/) I found a tutorial on how to do it. Of course, you don't have to follow it literally - you eg. don't have to create `/pub/upload` directory if you don't need it, and also you probably will have to adjust file/directory permissions to your needs, but the key point is that if you set `/usr/local/bin/scponly` as a user's shell, that user will be able to use scp/sftp, but will be unable to login interactively over ssh.