# Can we Migrate an FTP repository into SFTP in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, sftp

recently I got a ticket asking to change internal repository from FTP to Sftp. one repository have been configured and connected to internet in most secured network zone and that acts as a master server where we download all packages into it. from that server all client servers are sharing files through Ftp port no 21 and now I have to change it into Sftp. is it possible to do that.

Comment: Are you sure they said SFTP and not FTPS? What FTP Server Software is currently running? Are there any firewalls? Can you SSH to the server? You might consider seeking help from someone, because it is possible to do it and not very difficult, but also not a trivial task, especially as it is very much security related, there are many things you can do wrong.

Comment: SFTP has nothing to do with FTP, it might only share the user accounts. You can set it up completely separate from FTP and if it works fine, disable the ftp server software. There are good answers how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) or [How to set up a SFTP server with users chrooted in their home directories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49271/how-to-set-up-a-sftp-server-with-users-chrooted-in-their-home-directories).